# SlimDX: Cannot see Direct3D debug output in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, slimdx

1. I've installed the June 2010 SDK
2. Enabled the Debug Runtime in the DirectX Control Panel
3. - set the Debug Output Level to maximum (More)
4. Enabled unmanaged code debugging.

Result: The debug output from Direct3D is missing

However if I start the application externally and use dbgview.exe, the output is shown there.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of trial and error I found a solution to my problem.

Export your settings and check the value of the following setting:

```
<PropertyValue name="OutputOnOutputDebugString">1</PropertyValue>
```

I had 0 there. The most likely reason for this is that I use CSharp default settings. When using C++ environment default settings, that value is most likely already set.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go to the project properties of your managed executable, under the Debug tab, and turn on Native Code Debugging, which allows the messages through.