# DirectX 10 debug output not working

Tags: directx, visual-studio-debugging, slimdx, directx-10, debugview

I cannot make debug output for DirectX 10 to work for my simple C# application.
I've installed DirectX SDK, opened DirectX Control Panel and added application exe to list.

DirectX debug output was not shown in neither DebugView (when I start application exe manually) or Visual Studio 10 output console (when I start Debug).

I've added SlimDX to my project as a NuGet package, and the platform is set as x86.

I've run out of ideas how to make this work. Can someone think of something that I could try?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

When I created Direct3D9 simple example, debug was displayed. Direct3D10 is still not working.

Comment: How did you output the debug information?

Comment: I did not output my own info, I just need the one from DirectX. I keep on getting "E_INVALIDARG: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function" but I need more info to resolve this isssue.

Comment: show some code please.

Comment: This is the code I'm trying to debug:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934324/e-invalidarg-an-invalid-parameter-was-passed-to-the-returning-function

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with SharpDX rather than SlimDX, but hopefully the following will hold true.  In addition to installing the DirectX SDK and adding your executable to the debug list you should also:

- Open you project's properties and set 'Debug > Enable native code debugging' to true
- Create your DirectX device with the Debug device creation flag

Additionally, [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564445/slimdx-cannot-see-direct3d-debug-output-in-visual-studio-2010) suggests you may need to edit you VS settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help. From what I've read on the net, the same settings are needed for SlimDX, so I have already set them and it still did not work. :( As for additinal info, OutputOnOutputDebugString is set to 1 in my settings.