# E_INVALIDARG: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx, directx-10

I'm trying to make simple SlimDX example to test some performance vs GDI and unfortunately I got stuck on the very beginning. I've created simple Console Application in VS2010 and added this code to programs main method:

```
        // 0. STEP
        SlimDX.Direct3D10.Device device = new SlimDX.Direct3D10.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);
        SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory factory = new SlimDX.Direct2D.Factory();

        // 1. STEP
        Texture2DDescription textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription();
        textureDesc.Width = 512;
        textureDesc.Height = 512;
        textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        textureDesc.Format = SlimDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm;
        textureDesc.SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0);
        textureDesc.Usage = ResourceUsage.Default;
        textureDesc.BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget;
        textureDesc.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None;
        textureDesc.OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None;
        Texture2D maskTexture = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc);

        // 2. STEP
        SlimDX.DXGI.Surface surface = maskTexture.AsSurface();

        // 3. STEPpro
        RenderTargetProperties props = new RenderTargetProperties
        {
            HorizontalDpi = 96,
            VerticalDpi = 96,
            MinimumFeatureLevel = SlimDX.Direct2D.FeatureLevel.Default,
            PixelFormat = new PixelFormat(SlimDX.DXGI.Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied),
            Type = RenderTargetType.Default,
            Usage = RenderTargetUsage.None
        };
        RenderTarget target = RenderTarget.FromDXGI(factory, surface, props);
```

This crashes on the RenderTarget.FromDXGI call with this message:

```
Additional information: E_INVALIDARG: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function (-2147024809)
```

Unfortunately, I could not enable DirectX debug output as stated in this SO question:
[DirectX 10 debug output not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780008/directx-10-debug-output-not-working)

... so, this is all I've got.

**BUT**, I've tried this both at home (win8.1, vs2013) and at work (win7, vs2010sp1) and at home it works when I debug the app using Graphics Diagnostics from 2013. It doesn't work when I start regular debug or try to start exe manualy. At work it does not work at all.

Any ideas just from code? I'm kinda desperate here. :(

Comment: You need to pass `DeviceCreationFlags.Debug` to the `Device` constructor in order to get debug output. I am not sure if a render target may be created with an unknown pixel format. Does not make much sense to me. Especially if the underlying texture has a known format. Btw, it is much more comfortable to use the `Device.CreateWithSwapChain` method to create a device and render target.

Comment: 1) When I try to create device with Debug flag, I get this error: E_FAIL: An undetermined error occurred; 2) I've set render target's format to be the same as texture as you suggested; 3) I do not need to render to visual control so I'm not using swapchain. I just need to render some lines to texture and then export it to bitmap.

Comment: Have you installed the DirectX SDK which is included in the Windows SDK for some time?

Comment: On my home machine (win8.1) I've installed Windows SDK, and on my work machine (win7) I've installed DirectX SDK. I've also set DebugLevel.Information to D2D factory so that I can get more log info, but I keep getting "Unable to load D2D debug layer" even though I installed it additionaly from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940309%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your comment on my other answer. Here is the creation function I use:

```
    public static Texture2D CreateRenderTexture(this RenderHelper helper, int width, int height)
    {
        Texture2DDescription description = new Texture2DDescription
        {
            ArraySize = 1,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            Format = SlimDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            MipLevels = 1,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SampleDescription = new SlimDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
        };

        return new Texture2D(helper.Device, description);
    }
```